# What am I to you?

Tags: riddle, word

I am an object. I can come in many different colours. If you waste me, you are harming the environment. I am super flexible but after you bend me there are bend marks. I am cut in many different shapes changing my shape. People sometimes bend me in many various shapes and put me on display. Ink and lead are being coloured in my body every day. I am important and sometimes I am not so important. I am not a cloth. When technology advances, I will not be used so much and in time I will be old.

Who am I?

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't it be **What am I**?

Comment: I am new to puzzling, but what why does this post have 4 downvotes? I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> paper?

I am an object. I am in many different colours.

> Different colored paper or construction paper

If you waste me then you are harming the environment.

> You shouldn't waste paper. Recycling is a better alternative.

I am super flexible that after you bend me there are bent marks.

> There are creases if you fold paper.

I am being cut in many different shapes changing my shape.

> You can cut paper and change its shape.

Everyone sometimes bend me in many various shapes and put it in display.

> Origami

Ink and lead are being coloured in my body everyday.

> You draw pictures and color them.

I am important and sometimes I am not so important.

> You don't need paper to live, but it is still used for everyday life.

I am not a cloth.

> Obviously.

When technology advances, I will not be used so much and in time I will be old.

> You use less paper since there are ebooks, and there are tablets you can write and color on.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> PLASTIC?

*I am an object. I am in many different colours.*

> Many objects, in a wide variety of colours, are made of plastic.

*If you waste me then you are harming the environment.*

> Supposedly, wasting e.g. plastic bags harms the environment.

*I am super flexible that after you bend me there are bent marks.*

> Some kinds of plastic objects have this property.

*I am being cut in many different shapes changing my shape.*

> Many plastic objects get cut, changing their shape.

*Everyone sometimes bend me in many various shapes and put it in display.*

> Lots of people display plastic objects of various different shapes.

*Ink and lead are being coloured in my body.*

> Pens and pencils nowadays often have plastic exteriors.

*I am important and sometimes I am not so important.*

> Plastic objects can be very important to us, but we can still (as we used to) live without them.

*I am not a cloth.*

> Cloths aren't made of plastic.

I suppose it could also be something more specific...

Comment: Sorry but that's not the answer

Comment: Now that I think about it. It is plastic but I have another object in mind.

Comment: @toutsandnaushi What do you mean? The answer is something plastic, but more specific than just "plastic" generally?

Comment: The answer I thought was an object that is not plastic. I will now change the question a bit so that you could guess the answer.